# Unexpected behavior when validating password using abide validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation and I'm trying to make custom password validation using abide validation.

I need to make sure the password has at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 special character and this is the *regex* I'm using `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$/` which I got from this [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859632/regular-expression-for-password-validation).

But I can't submit the form, although I'm fulfilling the conditions for the password.

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo8qbLrp/5/) link, although I couldn't add foundation.js properly as *External Resource*, I get the same behavior I'm getting on my local machine.

So what is it that I'm missing.

Comment: Did you set up your environment as described in [*Using the JavaScript*](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/abide.html)?

Comment: Yes I did, and I don't have errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look on your developer console, you will see an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-'Times New Roman'-dropdown]

Nothing special. It's a known issue, that [has been described many times](http://jelaniharris.com/2014/fixing-foundation-5s-unrecognized-expression-syntax-error/). Before calling Foundation, add:

```
Foundation.global.namespace = '';
$(document).foundation();
```

Now fix an error with Modernizr, by adding it as a dependency - just include it *before* Foundation. [Link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js).

At the end your fiddle will look like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/fg16v5uc/