# Js regex validation for password

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, pattern-matching

Need some help for regular expression for password. 
Here is the matches:

- It should be at least 8 characters in length and the maximum length is 20 characters.
- Password MUST include at least 1 UPPERCASE alphabetic character, 1 LOWERCASE alphabetic character, 1 numeric character and 1 symbols ( @ # $ % ^ & ( ) _ + | ~ - = ` { } [ ] : ; < > ? , . /).
- The symbols that are NOT allowed are \ (back slash) or "(quotes).

It is quite difficult for me, I have limited experience in writing regular expressions.

I have this regexp but I don't see any way to deprecate \ and ". Added `(?=.*?["\\])` but it doesn't work.

Here is my regular

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-_()]).{8,20}$
```

Comment: "and the maximum length is 20 characters." --- this requirement is pointless.

Comment: Also [Regular Expression for password validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859632/regular-expression-for-password-validation/5859963#5859963).

Comment: The last requirement looks like it's for trying to prevent SQL injection... which is both hilarious and horrifying at the same time.

Comment: You don't win extra points for combining your requirements into one horrific regular expression. Split it up and check for each of your requirements separately. Future-you will thank you when they have to read it back in 6 months time