# regex with condition and suffix

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need help to create a regex that filters the strings have at least one number, uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and ends with "@xyz.sd"
I've tried that so far,

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9@\.]{12,25}
```

This full fill all the conditions except the "@xyz.sd" part. I tried to do that by,

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9@\.]+(@xyz.sd){12,25}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for password validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859632/regular-expression-for-password-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use another lookahead and you need to use anchors:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*@xyz\.sd$)[a-zA-Z0-9@.]{12,25}$
```

Or better you can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9@.]{5,18}@xyz\.sd$
```

Used quantifier range `{5,18}` instead of `{12,25}` as 7 characters will be consumed by `@xyz.sd`.

Comment: First one also works but you need to select multiline flag.  Though I would recommend using 2nd one.