# How to check if regex string does not start with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a working regex pattern in C# .NET which works great as expected. I just want to update this pattern to make sure any string that is compared with this regex is not start with any special Characters.

My Existsing Regex

```
(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!\{\}\[\]@#$%^&*()+_<>~-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,15}$");
```

For Example

TestHey@123! - **Pass**

@TestHey123! - **This should fail because special character at the beginning.**

Comment: What, _exactly_, do you define as a "special character"?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about your existing format? Why do you use so many lookaheads? Does this need to be a modification to your existing regex pattern, or can you run multiple regex/string checks to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Here is my current error message as per current patter

Comment: Password must be minimum 8 characters and maximum 15 characters in length.<br />Password must contain atleast </br>1 Uppercase character</br>1 Lowercase character</br>1 Numerical digit  and<br /> 1 Special character like ~!@$%^&*()_+-<>[]{}

Comment: these are my special characters: ~!@$%^&*()_+-<>[]{}

Comment: I wouldn't use _one_ regex to check a password's requirements. Split out your requirements into their own logic, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910204/1043380

Comment: Regexs are very powerful, but the regex shown in your question is very hard to understand. Complex regexs are hard to maintain and hard to understand; as indicated by your question. Adding extra checks into it will make it even more complex and even harder to maintain in the future. I suggest using several smaller regexs and some C# code to select when to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply specifying character class for first symbol of password separately from next seven to fifteen symbols:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!\{\}\[\]@#$%^&*()+_<>~-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[^!\{\}\[\]@#$%^&*()+_<>~-].{7,14}$
```

This will exclude specifically listed symbols. But other symbols like `ё` will be allowed.

If you want one of Latin letters or digits, you can specify this in the following way:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!\{\}\[\]@#$%^&*()+_<>~-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9].{7,14}$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YNKpsp/2).

Answer (score 1):

An idea to use a [`\b` word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at start to force a [word character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998519/net-regex-what-is-the-word-character-w) but exclude the underscore. The advantage is, that if applicable the regex will fail right away before triggering the lookaheads. Further I recommend to use [negation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) before the required character in the lookaheads (efficiency).

```
^\b(?!_)                         # start with a word character excluding underscore
(?=\D*\d)                        # look ahead for a digit preceded by any non-digits
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])                 # look ahead for an upper preceded by any non-upper
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])                 # look ahead for a lower preceded by any non-lower
(?=.*[!{}\[\]@\#$%^&*()<>_~+\-]) # one special character preceded by any characters
.{8,15}$                         # 8 to 15 characters until the end
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WAnVOH/1) (`\n` in the demo is just added for multiline testing) - Regex in one line:

```
^\b(?!_)(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=.*[!{}\[\]@\#$%^&*()<>_~+\-]).{8,15}$
```